# Parse XML to get node value in bash script?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, xml, xmllint

I would like to know how I can get the value of a node with the following paths:

```
config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/host
config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/username
config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/password
config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/dbname
```

from the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Tue, 11 Dec 2012 12:31:25 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[70e75d7969b900b696785f2f81ecb430]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[pass123]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[testdb]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Also I want to assign that value to the variable for further use. Let me know your idea.

Comment: Do not ever use bash to parse structured trees of arbitrary data. Use a real XML parser. I recommend [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash

Comment: Anyone with a Perl5 solution? I'd love to see how Perl5 and the Raku (a.k.a Perl6) solution below compare to each other.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `bash` and `xmllint` (as given by the tags):

```
xmllint --version  #  xmllint: using libxml version 20703

# Note: Newer versions of libxml / xmllint have a --xpath option which 
# makes it possible to use xpath expressions directly as arguments. 
# --xpath also enables precise output in contrast to the --shell & sed approaches below.
#xmllint --help 2>&1 | grep -i 'xpath'
```

---

```
{
# the given XML is in file.xml
host="$(echo "cat /config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/host/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell file.xml | sed '1d;$d')"
username="$(echo "cat /config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/username/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell file.xml | sed '1d;$d')"
password="$(echo "cat /config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/password/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell file.xml | sed '1d;$d')"
dbname="$(echo "cat /config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/dbname/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell file.xml | sed '1d;$d')"
printf '%s\n' "host: $host" "username: $username" "password: $password" "dbname: $dbname"
}

# output
# host: localhost
# username: root
# password: pass123
# dbname: testdb
```

---

In case there is just an XML string and the use of a temporary file is to be avoided, file descriptors are the way to go with `xmllint` (which is given `/dev/fd/3` as a file argument here):

```
set +H
{
xmlstr='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Tue, 11 Dec 2012 12:31:25 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[70e75d7969b900b696785f2f81ecb430]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[pass123]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[testdb]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
'

# exec issue
#exec 3<&- 3<<<"$xmlstr"
#exec 3<&- 3< <(printf '%s' "$xmlstr")
exec 3<&- 3<<EOF
$(printf '%s' "$xmlstr")
EOF

{ read -r host; read -r username; read -r password; read -r dbname; } < <(
       echo "cat /config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/*[self::host or self::username or self::password or self::dbname]/text()" | 
          xmllint --nocdata --shell /dev/fd/3 | 
          sed -e '1d;$d' -e '/^ *--* *$/d'
       )

printf '%s\n' "host: $host" "username: $username" "password: $password" "dbname: $dbname"

exec 3<&-
}
set -H


# output
# host: localhost
# username: root
# password: pass123
# dbname: testdb
```

Comment: Man page: http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html

Answer (score 14):

Using **xmllint** and the *--xpath* option, it is very easy. You can simply do this:

```
XML_FILE=/path/to/file.xml

HOST=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/host)' $XML_FILE
USERNAME=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/username)' $XML_FILE
PASSWORD=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/password)' $XML_FILE 
DBNAME=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/dbname)' $XML_FILE
```

If you need to get to an element's attribute, that's also easy using XPath. Imagine you have the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<addon id="screensaver.turnoff"
       name="Turn Off"
       version="0.10.0"
       provider-name="Dag Wieërs">
  ..snip..
</addon>
```

The needed shell statements would be:

```
VERSION=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(/addon/@version)' $ADDON_XML)
AUTHOR=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(/addon/@provider-name)' $ADDON_XML)
```

Answer (score 8):

Although there are a lot of answers already, I'll chime in with `xml2`.

```
$ xml2 < test.xml
/config/global/install/date=Tue, 11 Dec 2012 12:31:25 +0000
/config/global/crypt/key=70e75d7969b900b696785f2f81ecb430
/config/global/disable_local_modules=false
/config/global/resources/db/table_prefix
/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/host=localhost
/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/username=root
/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/password=pass123
/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/dbname=testdb
/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/initStatements=SET NAMES utf8
/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/model=mysql4
/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/type=pdo_mysql
/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/pdoType
/config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/active=1
/config/global/session_save=files
/config/admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName=admin
```

With a little magic you can even set those as variables directly:

```
$ eval $(xml2 < test.xml | tr '/, ' '___' | grep =)
$ echo $_config_global_resources_default_setup_connection_host          
localhost
```

Answer (score 4):

The following works when run against your test data:

```
{ read -r host; read -r username; read -r password; read -r dbname; } \
  < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -m /config/global/resources/default_setup/connection \
      -v ./host -n \
      -v ./username -n \
      -v ./password -n \
      -v ./dbname -n)
```

This puts the content into variables `host`, `username`, `password` and `dbname`.

Comment: xmlstarlet: command not found, so this command is not useful to me :(

Comment: @MagePsycho `bash` does not have any built-in support for XML parsing. You either need to have a tool that does (xmlstarlet, xsltproc, a modern Python, etc), or you can't parse XML correctly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is there a way to get the value may be using regex pattern or else?

Comment: @MagePsycho you can just install xmlstarlet. In any case, you should [never use regular expressions to parse (X)HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936).

Comment: @MagePsycho I was about to post the same link terdon already did. In short: No.

Comment: @MagePsycho Thank you for including sample data in the question; I've tested the code given against it, and updated the surrounding text appropriately.

Comment: Guys thanks for your input so far. But I can't use any extension as the server is not on our control. So I was thinking if there is harcoded way to get the values from that path, may be using grep/eval etc? Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

A pure `bash` function, just for the unfortunate case when you are not allowed to install anything appropriate. This may, and probably will, fail on more complicated XML:

```bash
function xmlpath()
{
  local expr="${1//\// }"
  local path=()
  local chunk tag data

  while IFS='' read -r -d '<' chunk; do
    IFS='>' read -r tag data <<< "$chunk"

    case "$tag" in
      '?'*) ;;
      '!–-'*) ;;
      '![CDATA['*) data="${tag:8:${#tag}-10}" ;;
      ?*'/') ;;
      '/'?*) unset path[${#path[@]}-1] ;;
      ?*) path+=("$tag") ;;
    esac

    [[ "${path[@]}" == "$expr" ]] && echo "$data"
  done
}
```

Usage:

```
bash-4.1$ xmlpath 'config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/host' < MagePsycho.xml
localhost
```

Known issues:

- slow
- searches only by tag names
- no character entity decoding

Answer (score 1):

Using `xq` (from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) to just get those strings out:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set -- \
        config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/host \
        config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/username \
        config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/password \
        config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/dbname

IFS=:

xq -r --arg path_string "$*" \
        'getpath(($path_string | split(":") | map(split("/")))[])' file.xml
```

This gives the path expressions to `xq` as a `:`-delimited list in the variable `$path_string`.  This string is subsequently split into its constituent paths, and these are then further split into path elements, so that one path internally may look like

```json
[
  "config",
  "global",
  "resources",
  "default_setup",
  "connection",
  "dbname"
]
```

The path arrays are given to the `getpath()` function which extracts the values located at those paths.

The output, for the given XML document, will be

```
localhost
root
pass123
testdb
```

Creating shell assignment statements instead:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set -- \
        config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/host \
        config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/username \
        config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/password \
        config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/dbname

eval "$(
    IFS=:
    xq -r --arg path_string "$*" '
            ($path_string | split(":") | map(split("/"))[]) as $path |
            "\($path[-1])=\(getpath($path)|@sh)"' file.xml
)"

printf 'host = "%s"\n' "$host"
printf 'user = "%s"\n' "$username"
printf 'pass = "%s"\n' "$password"
printf 'database = "%s"\n' "$dbname"
```

For the given paths and XML document, the `xq` statement above would create the output

```
host='localhost'
username='root'
password='pass123'
dbname='testdb'
```

This would be safe to `eval` to assign the `host`, `username`, `password`, and `dbname` shell variables.

The output of the script would be

```
host = "localhost"
user = "root"
pass = "pass123"
database = "testdb"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of php command line interface coding in bash scripts to handle several complex scripts that actually span over multiple lines of coding. First, try to make your solution using PHP scripts, and then later on pass the parameters using CLI mode. Thus, you can get control over superb usages of XML parsers.

The environment seems that you can use PHP in client mode via ssh/shell access.

```
php -f yourxmlparser.php
```

Now, do all the things within your php file. Make use of command line parameters it can take.

You can even assign that return values to Shell environment to continue rest of your shell scripts.

And the other way is to use |grep option to match your required value within the xml file, if you are pretty sure of the structure of your xml file that does not change over time.

Comment: Use case for all of the above has merit. 5 Stars for all combined.

Answer (score 0):

This comment use only sh/bash commands and methods !
/test.xml is your XML type file at first question...

```
#!/bin/sh

cat /test.xml | while read line;do
[ "$(echo "$line" | grep "<host>")" ]&& echo "host: $(echo $line |  cut -f3 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']')"
[ "$(echo "$line" | grep "<username>")" ]&& echo "username: $(echo $line |  cut -f3 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']')"
[ "$(echo "$line" | grep "<password>")" ]&& echo "password: $(echo $line |  cut -f3 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']')"
[ "$(echo "$line" | grep "<dbname")" ]&& echo "dbname: $(echo $line |  cut -f3 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']')"
done
```

output:

```
host: localhost
username: root
password: pass123
dbname: testdb
```

if u want write this values to file use this method :

```
#!/bin/sh

cat /test.xml | while read line;do
[ "$(echo "$line" | grep "<host>")" ]&& echo "$line" |  cut -f3 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']' > /config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/host
[ "$(echo "$line" | grep "<username>")" ]&& echo "$line" |  cut -f3 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']' > /config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/username
[ "$(echo "$line" | grep "<password>")" ]&& echo "$line" |  cut -f3 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']' > /config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/password
[ "$(echo "$line" | grep "<dbname")" ]&& echo "$line" |  cut -f3 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']' > /config/global/resources/default_setup/connection/dbname
done
```

this method will overwrite your local files used only getting values (your datas will lost from output files)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

I recognize the OP requested a `bash` script, but since other answers have deviated from this requirement, here's a Raku solution (4 one-liners):

```
raku -MXML -e 'my $xml=open-xml($*ARGFILES.Str); $xml.lookfor(:TAG<host>).>>.cdata>>.data.put;'
raku -MXML -e 'my $xml=open-xml($*ARGFILES.Str); $xml.lookfor(:TAG<username>).>>.cdata>>.data.put;'
raku -MXML -e 'my $xml=open-xml($*ARGFILES.Str); $xml.lookfor(:TAG<password>).>>.cdata>>.data.put;'
raku -MXML -e 'my $xml=open-xml($*ARGFILES.Str); $xml.lookfor(:TAG<dbname>).>>.cdata>>.data.put;'
```

OUTPUT:

```
localhost
root
pass123
testdb
```

Briefly, Raku is called at the bash command line, and `-M` module `XML` is loaded with the command `-MXML`. The xml file is opened with `open-xml` and stored in the `$xml` object. Then the `$xml` object is queried recursively for desired tags [ in point of fact, the `lookfor(...)` code is a shortcut for `elements(..., :RECURSE)` ]. Then the `CDATA` values are extracted.

There are other ways to get the desired data, such as simply walking the `XML`-parse tree:

```
raku -MXML -e 'my $xml=open-xml($*ARGFILES.Str); .cdata.map(*.data).put for $xml.nodes[1].nodes[7].nodes[3].nodes[1].nodes[1,3,5,7];'
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
raku -MXML -e 'my $xml=open-xml($*ARGFILES.Str); .cdata>>.data.put for $xml.nodes[1][7][3][1][1,3,5,7];'
```

The two lines of code above each return:

```
localhost
root
pass123
testdb
```

https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML
https://raku.org/

[For alternative solutions in Raku, there's also the `LibXML` module, which provides bindings to the (possibly faster) `libxml2` library. See https://modules.raku.org/dist/LibXML:cpan:WARRINGD].