# How extract string between start and end pattern with sed AWK?

Tags: awk, sed

I have html file , I want extract string between pattern . 
this file look like this :

```
<span>aghahan.com</span>
<span>pouyamannequin.com</span>
```

i need that domain with span : aghahan.com , pouyamannequin.com

I am try with this command :

```
sed -e 's/>!\(.*\)>.com<\/span>/\1/' domain.txt
```

but I get wrong result . thankful if anybody help me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936 and the xmllint and xmlstarlet answers at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83385/133219

Answer (score 1):

As each line begins with `<span>` and ends with `</span>`:

```
sed 's|<span>\(.*\)</span>|\1|' domain.txt
```

You can also do it this way with `awk` by setting the field separator as either `<` or `>` and printing the third column:

```
awk -F '[<>]' '{print $3}' domain.txt
```

Output:

```
aghahan.com
pouyamannequin.com
```

These are the simplest ways that it can be done and it will also work if the lines have trailing white space.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`

```
 sed 's/\(.*\)>\(.*\)<\(.*\)/\2/g' domain.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With `python` and `BeautifulSoup`:

```
python -c '
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open("domain.txt", "r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),"html.parser")
for span in soup.find_all("span"):
  print(span.string)
'
```

Might be a bit overkill for your simple task, but will work much better and will be easier on more difficult tasks, e.g. if you have different html like:

```html
<span>
 aghahan.com
</span>
<span>
 pouyamannequin.com
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ">" '{print $2}' filename| sed "s/<.*//g"
```

output

```
aghahan.com
pouyamannequin.com
```